# Why is the Lucene.NET IndexSearcher returning zero results?

Tags: c#, indexing, lucene.net

I recently started working with Lucene.NET and I have some problems: I have used an `IndexWriter` to index my documents in `C:\\TestIndex` which I guess it worked since it generated several `.fnm`, `.frq`, `.cfx`, `.tii`, `.tis` files.

The problem is when trying to make a simple search through them, I never get any results back. Below is the code I use,

```
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.QueryParsers;
using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Store;
using Lucene.Net.Util;

//Provide the directory where index is stored
Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(newSystem.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\TestIndex")); 

IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
Searcher indexSearch = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

Analyzer std = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, "text", std);
Query qry = parser.Parse("morning");

// true opens the index in read only mode
Searcher srchr = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.Open(directory, true));

TopScoreDocCollector cllctr = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(100, true);

ScoreDoc[] hits = cllctr.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
srchr.Search(qry, cllctr); 

for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
{
    int docId = hits[i].Doc;
    float score = hits[i].Score;
    Document doc = srchr.Doc(docId);
    Console.WriteLine("Searched from Text: " + doc.Get("text"));
}
```

I tried several approaches but I never get any result. Do you have any idea?

Below is indexing code,

```
IndexWriter indexWriter = 
    new IndexWriter(
        luceneDir, 
        new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29), 
        true, 
        IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

string[] listOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Projects\lucene.net-trunk\build\vs2010\demo\MyTestProject\TestDocs");

foreach (string s in listOfFiles)
{
    String content = File.ReadAllText(s);
    Document doc = new Document();
    String title = s;

    // adding title field
    doc.Add(new Field("title", title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));  
    doc.Add(new Field("content", content, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

    indexWriter.AddDocument(doc);
}

indexWriter.Optimize();
indexWriter.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use luke to inspect the index to ensure it has data also you can perform searches to validate your search criteria

http://www.getopt.org/luke/

**EDIT** - (Luke will work with lucene and lucene.net indexes you will need to install java to use)

**EDIT**

Update the line

```
Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser parser = new Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "text", std);
```

With

```
Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser parser = new Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "content", std);
```

You have set the default search field to `text` which doesn't exist

Also you are trying to fetch the wrong field in your `console.write` line

Comment: I get this error with Luke: "Incompatible format version: 2 expected 1 or lower" EDIT - I found a workaround i guess

Comment: Good sign can you perform searches?  Try "text: morning"

Comment: I am trying to run moreLikeThis.  Does it need any special parameter to get docs ?

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Projects\lucene.net-trunk\build\vs2010\demo\MyTestProject\TestDocs\suspicious-document00001.txt"));
          
            IndexReader ir = Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
            MoreLikeThis mlt = new MoreLikeThis(ir);
            Query query = mlt.Like(reader);

            
            Searcher srchr = new IndexSearcher(ir);

            TopDocs topDocs = srchr.Search(query, 10);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25845/discussion-between-bogdan-sara-and-dreamwalker)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try explicitely specifying the field you're searching? for example:

```
    Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser parser = new Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "text", std);
    Lucene.Net.Search.Query qry = parser.Parse("content: morning");
```

I think that Lucene requires you to tell it on which field(s) (title, content...) you want to run your query.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the same analyzer when indexing and searching (in your case it's `StandardAnalyzer` I guess):

```
using Lucene.Net.Analysis;
using Lucene.Net.Documents;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Store;

...

Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\TestIndex"));

var writer = new IndexWriter(
    directory, 
    new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29), 
    true, 
    new MaxFieldLength(int.MaxValue));
```

**UPDATE**

I'm using a slightly different approach for searching but, anyway, maybe you need to swap these two lines:

```
ScoreDoc[] hits = cllctr.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
srchr.Search(qry, cllctr);
```

So it becomes:

```
srchr.Search(qry, cllctr); 
ScoreDoc[] hits = cllctr.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
```

meaning that the collector first collects the results when the search is executed and then you get your scored documents via the collector instance.

Comment: Below is my code for generating the index.. it is the same:
-------------------------------------------------------------


                IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(luceneDir, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't work. I suspect it might be related about my solution references, maybe I don't have the appropriate setup